# How can I import "Vue" in a ViteJS project, or get the Template HTML content in another way?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

When trying to import 'Vue' in my ViteJS project in order to instantiate a new Vue() instance, for both 
`import vue from 'vue'`<sup>1</sup>

 and 
`import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'`<sup>2</sup>
I get the following errors:

`"The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/vue.js?v=8f63bc36' does not provide an export named 'default'"`<sup>1</sup>

 `"Invalid left-hand side in assignment"`<sup>2</sup>

Has anyone faced a similar problem or found a solution to this?
 Thanks in advance!

**for the ones wondering what I am trying to do, I want to get the HTML content of the 'template' section of a Vue component as a string

Comment: `import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'; console.log(getCurrentInstance().ctx)`